# Access Excel VBA find cells with same value under a column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I create an Excel export data with Access VBA. But I need to find the same values and order them. I want to find all same values under A and cut them next to each other with their specs. Here is an example, what I want to do. I wrote some VBA codes but it is extremely slow, it takes 10-15 minutes. I have 3000 columns.

from this one:

```
A         B           C
```

1  value1    spec1        spec1

2  value2     spec2       spec2

3  value1    spec3        spec3

4  value3    spec4        spec4

to this one:

```
A         B           C           D            E
```

1  value1   spec1        spec1      spec3         spec3 (from A3)

2  value2

3  value3

4  value

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qryExportPassiv", "C:\Temp\ExportPassivEExi.xls", False

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\ExportPassivEExi.xls")


wb.Activate

intlengthwb = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Debug.Print intlengthwb

k = 2
Z = 1

Do While (k < intlengthwb)

For j = 2 To intlengthwb

If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
Z = Z + 1
Debug.Print Z
End If

Next j

k = k + 1

Loop
```

Comment: It's slow but it works?

Comment: It takes 3 hours, it cannot be that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with RecordSet, took just 10 seconds.